# How to get the background color of element within CSS file?

Tags: css

I have an animation in my application, and I also have a dark mode theme.
The animation have the following transitions, inside @keyframes : 
(It has more phases, but it's irrelevant for my question)

```
0% {
    transform: rotateX(0);
    background: #fff;
    border-color: black;
    }

45% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    background: #fff;
    border-color: black;
    }
```

I want to change the background property, so it will check what is the background color right now, and then apply the same value.
Something like

```
  background: var(--background-color);
```

(When I declare --background-color to be the current background color) 
What is the right way to do it?

Comment: How many different background colors will be there? One specific color for each theme? If so, create different animations for each theme and apply them when needed.

Comment: Yes, one specific color for each theme.  I am using Angular Material to define the themes. If I am creating different animations, do you know how I can apply them when needed? 

I just tried to define the dark-theme animations inside the file of it, and also applying it to the right div class - but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution to my problem, but it's a bit different than my question.
Instead of checking what is the background color right now, I declared a css variable in Body of the main page. This variable will contain the background color of the current theme.

Whenever the theme is changed, I also change the css variable with:

```
document.body.style.setProperty('--current-background', 'backgroundColor');
```

but instead of backgroundColor, I just write the background color of the theme that user has switched to.

In my animation, I set

```
background-color: var(--current-background);
```

and it works as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to get the background of an element and set another element to that color. Checkout:

https://www.w3resource.com/jquery-exercises/jquery-css-exercise-1.php

Comment: Although I prefer not to use jQuery, if I will try this way - How I can apply the color inside the animation?
Anyway, if you have a way to get the color and apply it inside the animation, it can be helpfull. I am also using Angular, if that helps.

Comment: Your answer is ok, but it would be nicer if you had added a simple example to better explain what you meant